# Is there an easier way to keep an element from scrolling past the top of the page?

Tags: css, scrollbar

http://jsfiddle.net/XjqmS/

After I corrected my content tag to `position:relative`, that element won't stay at its position. Instead, it scrolls above the image. I want the page to scroll, not the element. Is that possible?

Comment: if u want the content not to scroll, give it a position of fixed. I am unable to understand to what are you reffering to.

Comment: If I set the position to fixed, the entire page won't scroll. That's my problem--I need the page to scroll, but the actual element is scrolling rather than the page.

Comment: I am really sorry. I have below average IQ. which img are you reffering to and which element you want to scroll?

Comment: I don't want the element to scroll. I want the page to scroll, but the content element is scrolling instead and moving past the header img banner on the website. If it isn't clear on the jsfiddle, you can look at the actual website, duffautosales.com.

Comment: Ok. See if I understand you. On your web page you have a first p which has a style element. Why?. The second p contains the img which I assume you are reffering as header img with the "DUFF AUTOSALES". Next you have div#content which has a div.content. Now to the div#content, you are using position: relative with left: 347px; So it "moves" 347px from its origional position and this cause it to grow larger than the width of the page and cause it to scroll horzitionally. The whole page does not scroll vertically beacuse there is not enough content. Try this.

Comment: Remove position: relative; and left: 347px from the div#content. Give it a margin-left: 350px; and the same width as div.content.

Answer (score 1):

I think redoing the layout would remove the issue with using `position:fixed` :D

***See here: http://jsfiddle.net/SAfLK/***

**html**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">FIXED HEADER</div>
    <div id="navigation">FIXED NAVIGATION</div>
    <div id="content">
        CONTENT GOES HERE
        <img src="http://www.dummyimage.com/200/" />
        <br />
        <img src="http://www.dummyimage.com/200/" />
        <br />
        <img src="http://www.dummyimage.com/200/" />
        <br />
        <img src="http://www.dummyimage.com/200/" />
        <br />
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
/*adjust dimensions as necessary*/

html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#wrapper {
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    width:400px;
    background-color:#efe;
    margin:0 auto; 
}

#header {
    height:50px;
    background-color:#ded;
}

#navigation, #content {
    position:absolute;
    top:50px; /*set to header's height*/
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}

/* #content and #navigation's width should add up to the #wrapper's width*/

#navigation {
    width:150px;
    background-color:#cdc;
}

#content {
    overflow:auto;
    width:250px;
    left:150px; /*set to whatever navigations's width is*/
    background-color:#fef;
}
```